# IP Neighbour to get IPV4 address

Tags: linux, networking

IP Neighbour returns IPV6 addresses for some devices though these devices all have IPV4. How can i set it so it only returns IPV4 addresses?

```
fe80::a7a:4cff:fe9f:a03a dev br-lan lladdr 08:7a:4c:9f:a0:3a STALE
fe80::8ebe:beff:fede:afaf dev br-lan lladdr 8c:be:be:de:af:af STALE
fe80::ba8d:12ff:fe24:3076 dev br-lan lladdr b8:8d:12:24:30:76 STALE
192.168.0.22 dev br-lan  FAILED
192.168.0.21 dev br-lan lladdr b8:8d:12:24:30:76 DELAY
192.168.0.1 dev br-lan lladdr 00:00:00:00:02:00 STALE
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with how IP Neighbour is called, but you could pipe your output into grep like this: `grep "[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}" -E`

Comment: @ChrisForrence `ip neigh show`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I **believe** `ip nei s to 0/0` and `ip nei s to 0::0/0` show only IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, respectively.

```
$ ip nei help
Usage: ip neigh { add | del | change | replace } { ADDR [ lladdr LLADDR ]
          [ nud { permanent | noarp | stale | reachable } ]
          | proxy ADDR } [ dev DEV ]
       ip neigh {show|flush} [ to PREFIX ] [ dev DEV ] [ nud STATE ]
```

Comment: Love this answer, saved.

Answer (score 2):

All `ip` commands take `-family inet` option, or `-4` for short.

[man ip(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip.8.html):

```
   OPTIONS := ... -f[amily] { inet | inet6 | ipx | dnet | link }
```

...

```
   -4     shortcut for -family inet.
```

So you can just do

```
ip -4 neigh show
```

Answer (score 1):

As [the man page states](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-neighbour.8.html):

> The IPv4 neighbour table is also known by another name - the ARP table.

Try `arp -a` instead.

EDIT:

[nodakai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25555693/1454048) is better, in that it retains the output from `ip neigh` that `arp` does not.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the output of IP Neighbor into grep, showing only those IP addresses that match IPv4 addresses.

```
ip neigh show | \
  grep "^[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}" -E
```

To explain the expression, it searches, from the beginning of the string, for one to three digits, followed by a period. This repeats three times, then finishes with a final search for one to three digits.